# Is it possible to aggregate over a whole string in a Logstash query?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

We're trying out Logstash with Kibana 4.0.0-BETA2 and we have a field that is called "LogMessage" that contains the actual logmessage without any timestamps and other cruft.

When I naively try to build a query to aggregate over the top three "LogMessage":s, using "Aggregation=Terms", "Field=LogMessage", "Order=Top" and "Size=5", Kibana generates the following aggregation:

```
  "aggs": {
    "agg_120": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "LogMessage",
        "size": 3,
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The problem is that it aggregates over single words in the logmessages. I get the keys "1", "application" and "0000".

Is it possible to aggregate over the whole LogMessage string?

Comment: Try aggregating by field "LogMessage.raw".

Comment: Adding .raw to the field resulted in no hits and no buckets.

Comment: What version of Logstash are you using?

Comment: The latest, 1.4.2 I think it is.